# Testing for a backslash in a string

Tags: php, string

So I'm writing a PHP script that will read in a CSS file, then put the comments and actual CSS in separate arrays. The script will then build a page with the CSS and comments all nicely formatted.

The basic logic for the script is this:

- Read in a new line
- If it starts with a forward slash or
  ends with an opening bracket, set a
  bool for CSS or comments to true
- Add that line to the appropriate
  element in the appropriate array
- If the last character is a backslash
  (end of a comment) or the first
  character is a closing bracket (end
  of a CSS tag), set necessary bool to
  false
- Rinse, repeat

If someone sees an error in that, feel free to point it out, but I think it should do what I want.

The tricky part is the last if statement, checking if the last character is a backslash. Right now I have:

```
if ($line{(strlen($line) - 3)} == "\\") {do stuff}
```

where $line is the last line read in from the file. Not entirely sure why I have to go back 3 characters, but I'm guessing it's because there's a newline at the end of each string when reading it in from a file. However, this if statement is never true, even though there are definitely lines which end with slashes. This

```
echo "<br />str - 3: " . $line{(strlen($line)-3)};
```

even returns a backslash, yet the if statement is never trigged.

Comment: Have you tried adding some characters to new line before loop?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean? I've checked $line, and it definitely contains a string when it's getting tested.

Comment: You may have `\r\n`, `\r` or `\n` line endings.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because $line{(strlen($line) - 3)} in your if statement is returning one backslash, while the if statement is looking for two. Try using

```
substr($line, -2)
```

instead. (You might have to change it to -3. The reason for this is because the newline character might be included at the end of the string.)

Comment: Doesn't the backslash need to be escaped though? I thought the if statement would actually be testing for one slash, not two.

Comment: Hmm, I apologize. Didn't think about that. In that case I'm not sure what's going wrong, but I still think substr would be a better route in this case.

Comment: I tried a substring too, and it returns a backslash, but the if statement still fails. I did come to an important realization though - comments close with a forward slash, not a backslash. Problem (kinda) solved!

Answer (score 0):

@mcritelli: CSS comments look like `/* comment */` though, so just searching for a backslash won't tell you if it's starting or ending the comment. Here's a very basic script I tested which loops through a 'line' and can do something at the beginning and end of a comment --

```
<?php
$line  = "/* test rule */";
$line .= ".test1 { ";
$line .= "  text-decoration: none; ";
$line .= "}/* end of test rule */";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($line); $i++) 
{
    if ($line[$i] . $line[$i + 1] == "/*")
    {
        // start of a comment, do something
    }
    elseif ($line[$i] . $line[$i + 1] == "*/")
    {
        // end of a comment, do something
    }
}
?>
```